# Using .env variables in Dockerfile and Node

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, environment-variables

I'm trying to use postgres using Docker. Currently, it is working fine but the `user`, `password` and the `database` is exposed to the world. Please have a look at my code.

**Dockerfile**

```
# Use the official PostgreSQL image as the base image
FROM postgres:15.4

# Set the environment variables for PostgreSQL
ENV POSTGRES_USER=admin
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin@12345
ENV POSTGRES_DB=pern_todo

# Expose the PostgreSQL port
EXPOSE 5432
```

I'm currently using `docker build -t app-postgres-image .` to build an image and `docker run --name pern-todo-postgres-container -d -p 5432:5432 app-postgres-image` to build a container.

Now I want to add these ENV variables in .env file so that I can use this in both my JavaScript code as well as while building Docker image and container. Please tell me how I achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your Dockerfile contains other trully usefull instructions, we can simply totally drop it for this example. Whatever the case, you do not want to set those vars at build time.

## With `docker` only

First create your `.env` file containing your credentials. You probably want to ignore this file so that it is not commited to your versionning system

As an example to create it from your command line:

```bash
cat <<EOF > .env
POSTGRES_USER=admin
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin@12345
POSTGRES_DB=pern_todo
EOF
```

Now this is done, simply start the postgres image with those environment varialbles from the `.env` file:

```bash
docker run --name pern-todo-postgres-container -d -p 5432:5432 --env-file=.env
```

Similarly, you can start an other container with the same environment file to get the credentials in your nodejs image for example

## With `docker compose`

This is probably easier on the long run since you will be able to add your other container as a service in the same file. Moreover, your will have a better control of which values in the `.env` file should be passed to which container (as you may want to add more).

To start with, make sure the current directory you're in as meaningfull name related to your project (e.g. `pern-todo`). This is the default name that `compose` will use.

Create your `.env` file exactly as above then add the following `compose.yml` file

```yaml
---
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15.4
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-appuser}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-verysecret}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-adefaultdb}
```

Note the syntax for environment var values => `${<NAME>:-<defaultvalue>}`. This ensures that, if you did not provide a `.env` file and a var does not exist, it will be replaced with the default value.

Then start your service (note: the compose plugin must be installed for this command to succeed)

```
docker compose up -d
```

You can verify that everithing worked ok with the following command for example which should get you directly to the `psql` prompt:

```bash
$ docker compose exec postgres psql -U admin pern_todo
psql (15.4 (Debian 15.4-1.pgdg120+1))
Type "help" for help.

pern_todo=# exit
```

And you can stop your service with:

```
docker compose down
```

## Going further

There are many other things you can go on with which are the scope of this question. As a non exhaustive list:

- adding volume(s) to your docker service to keep data between run
- provide init script to your docker service to scaffold a database when starting from an empty volume
- add your service containing your javascript project to your compose file
- add specific networks to your compose file to better manage communication between services.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt. I just have one question. In .env file, I have also written PORT=5000 which is meant for node.js app. My question is if I run docker run command will this have any effect considering postgres run on a complete different port?

Comment: 1) this is why you should be docker compose 2) rhetoric question: what happens if you set that variable in your current postgres container?

Comment: I honestly don't know. Please tell me.

Comment: [It takes less time to try it than to ask me again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592). But the answer is: it does not change anything if you are not using that var anywhere.